# When creating a SQL view can i have temp tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I am using Microsoft SQL -- I need to create a view that pulls a lot of data - about 100 columns, but in order to make it efficient I have to filter the data on 3-5 different joins first. There is no clean way to do this without a few temp tables. But the view doesn't seem to allow me. it Just says "incorrect sytax near 'AS'"

my code looks like this

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[LV_ViewName] AS

declare @table1 table
(
customer_no int,
name varchar(100),
...
)
```

several of those followed

by a

```
declare #work table
(
customer_no int,
name varchar(100),
--    all encompasing data
...
)
```

Comment: "*There is no clean way to do this without a few temp tables*" - this sounds *really* strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, you cannot have a temporary table in a view.  As the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) says:

> The SELECT clauses in a view definition cannot include the following:
>
> . . .
>
> - A reference to a temporary table or a table variable.

However, you should be able to express your view using common table expressions (CTEs) and subqueries.  If you really do find that you need temporary tables, then you can can use table variables and a table-valued function.

Answer (score -2):

Don't create a view - create a Stored Procedure!

Comment: I have to create a view with all the data - a massive amount of data and from that create about 4 stored procedures that filter out based on different necessary elements. So I was told to do it this way.